# S3 Bucket Signed URLs to grant access to pictures

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having a brainstorming issue on how to get user uploaded pictures viewed by only the friends of the users.

So what I've come up with so far is:

1. Create a DynamoDB table for each user, with a dynamic list of friends/new friends added.
2. Generate a Signed URL for every user-uploaded picture.
3. Allow access to the Signed URL to every friend listed in the DynamoDB table to view set picture/s.

Does this sound correct? Also, would I technically have just one bucket for ALL user uploaded pictures? Something about my design sounds off...

Can anyone give me a quick tutorial on how to accomplish this via Java?

Comment: I am not sure there is enough information here. Also it could be any type of data, restricting access by users is a basic element of all user authentication and authorization functions provided by any backend. What are you using as to manage your users? What tech are you already using? What code do you already have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using Cognito to authenticate users. I'm still new to AWS so I'm not sure what I'm doing to be honest. I've developed a fully functioning login/register using Cognito and android studio. so I'm able to list all my registered and verified users. So my question is, users will upload pictures to S3, then what steps do I need to take to enable only their friends to view set pictures? is this done through dynamo?

Comment: No, this won't work because signed URLs expire. You'd need to supply a new signed URL to each authenticated user at the time that the user requests the image file. Yes, you can use one bucket to maintain multiple users' files (just partition them with some kind of prefix based on the unique user id). Also, read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html.

Comment: You don't "allow access to" signed URLs.  A signed URL is self-contained and possession of the URL allows access to the resource.  Question: will these images be in HTML on a web page, or this a mobile app that's doing something like fetching a list?  If it's an app, how exactly does the app learn what images are available to download?

Answer (score 1):

There two basic approaches:

- Permissions in Amazon S3, or
- Application-controlled access to object in Amazon S3

**Permissions in Amazon S3**

You can provide credentials (either via IAM or Amazon Cognito) that allow users to access a **particular path within an Amazon S3 bucket**. For example, each user could have their own path within the bucket.

Your application would generate URLs that include signatures that identify them as that particular user and Amazon S3 would grant access to the objects.

One benefit of this approach is that you could provide the AWS credentials to the users and they could **interact directly with AWS**, such as using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to upload/download files without having to always go via your application.

**Application-controlled access to object in Amazon S3**

In this scenario, users have no permissions within Amazon S3. Instead, each time that your application wishes to generate a URL to an object in S3 (eg in an `<img>` tag), you created a **pre-signed URL**. This will grant access to the object for a limited time. It only takes a couple of lines of code and can be done within the application without communication with AWS to generate the URL.

There is no need to *store* pre-signed URLs. They are generated on-the-fly.

The benefit of this approach is that **your application has full control over which objects they can access**. Friends could share pictures with other users and the application would grant access, whereas the first method only grants access to objects within the user's specific path.