# Item-level permissions to AWS S3 uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on storing image files in AWS S3 for users of my site. I want to allow the users to access only to the images they uploaded through my site (not those uploaded by other users). When I upload an image to S3, I can create a url to view that image, but I want that to be only viewable by the user who uploaded it.

A high-level example of this might be how instagram users can make their accounts private. Say Suzy makes her account private and has allowed 0 followers. At this point, even if other people have a url to an image from Suzy, they can't see it.

I've looked into using an Origin Access Identity, but it seems like that restricts access to the whole bucket, rather than on an item by item basis.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: How do you authenticate your users? How will your users access the content in S3?

Comment: You can probably use signed URLs for that.

Comment: See also: [S3 Bucket Signed URLs to grant access to pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395292/174777)

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using signed URLs with boto3 and got it to work.